# Why is joda time get difference between hours taking so much of memory

Tags: android, jodatime, android-traceview

I have the following function:

```
public static int getDiffHour(Date first) {
        int hoursBetween = Hours.hoursBetween(new LocalDate(first), new LocalDate()).getHours();
        return hoursBetween;
    }
```

I am trying to get difference in hours between two dates.

Here is my Traceview:

[image]

The function is taking crazy amounts of time and resource to execute - what do I miss here. My service is getting killed on 5.0.1 due to this enormous CPU time taken by this function.

#### Edit:

Digging down deeper, I find that 99% of the CPU time is taken by LocalDate init. Is there a way I can avoid that and supply a date precalculated?

#### Edit 2: After implementing Joda 2.6:

[image]

Comment: This seems to be a known issue. Found this: http://java-performance.info/joda-time-performance/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [issue](https://github.com/JodaOrg/joda-time/issues/196) might have been **solved with the newest Joda-Time-release v2.6** because the class initialization of class `DateTimeZone` (where you observe huge amounts of time spent) no longer calls the method `setProvider0()`, see also this [commit](https://github.com/JodaOrg/joda-time/commit/0a7eed9c47188e104079587966094770b80a4047#diff-5fc6a13208b27668b27b7f75a6da56a6).

Comment: I will just download the latest jar and update here - actually my bug seems to be double edged. Its a mix of memory consumption and [this](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=63793)

Comment: It has dropped from 90.7% to 89.9 percent with the new jar. Consuming a lot of resources to init the LocalDate.

Comment: @Skynet Can you please show your new trace (with Joda-Time v2.6)?

Comment: Bro, I think I had misinterpreted / used a wrong trace file. The performance has increased tremendously, I am posting the new traceview image in my original question.